# Magento 2: How to use min() and max() function to filter high price or quantity

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I want to get the highest price from the database using `max()` on **price** column and low quantity using `min()` on **qty** column. How can I write the query?

Comment: you want both the statement in one collection ?

Comment: yes i want to select product with low price and high quantity.

Comment: Any help on this @MohammadMujassam

Comment: kindly accept the ans if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approach you can go for.. one I'll list here which I have used.

first you need to make the join of product collection with the table `cataloginventory_stock_item` with the current website id condition

for ex. `$productJoinStockCollection->getSelect()->where('website_id = '. $currentWebId);`

then again for sorting:
`$productJoinStockCollection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('-price ASC, qty DESC'));`

you can achieve your desired sorting by exchanging the position of **price, qty** in **Zend_Db_Expr**

Hope this will help you to get the desired result.

Note: Make sure you are joint the product collection & inventory table properly.